# ASP.NET, Entity Put request for an item does not update database relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, crud

My model is made up of three Entities : Device, Group and User.

It looks like this, with many-to-many relationships between Device-Group and Group-User :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuBMv.jpg

(sorry, can't include image in body yet)

I issue PUT commands through the controller generated by Visual Studio

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutDevice(int id, Device device)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
    }
     if (id != device.DeviceId)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
     db.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Modified;
    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
    }
     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

The Entity update seems to go well when I change the simple properties like Name or Description. 
However my problem is that **when I try to change the Groups in the Device, the database does not seem to be updated**.
I was under the impression that EF's whole purpose was to manage the implied change in the many-to-many relationship automatically. Do I have to take an additional step explicitly?

The Device model looks like :

```
public partial class Device
{
    public Device()
    {
        this.Groups = new HashSet<Group>();
    }

    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Here a screenshot of the Device object when entering the PutDevice(int id, Device device) method:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQgjg.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the debugger I get no error, it returns HttpStatusCode.OK. The content of the device that is passed to PutDevice() is visible on the screenshot at the end of my question. 
But then when I call GetDevices(), the Device still has the old groups associated to it.

Answer (score 0):

Reattaching entities in a disconnected scenario has two steps:

1. Reattach the entity graph to the context so that it is tracked
2. Set the state for each entity in the graph

Setting the `EntityState` to `Modified` on the root `Device` entity will attach all entities in the object graph to the context. However, it will mark all child entities with the `Unchanged` state. This corresponds to step 1 above.

To get the child entities to persist their changes, you will need to iterate over graph and set the changed state to `Modified`, as per step 2 above.

For example:

```
context.Entry(device.Group).State = EntityState.Modified
```